# Alternate way to pass graphql auth in nuxt3 using apollo client?

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo-client, nuxtjs3, cloudflare-workers

I'm currently using the following config in my nuxt.config.ts for apollo client, however I receive the error:

**The 'credentials' field on 'RequestInitializerDict' is not implemented**

```
  apollo: {
    clients: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: "https://endpoint.here.com/graphql",
        httpLinkOptions: {
          credentials: 'include'
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Additionally, Ive tried:

```
 apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        uri: 'https://endpoint.here.com/graphql',
        authenticationType: 'Bearer',
      },
    },
```

However, it seems this also uses the credentials field. It seems that Cloudflare Workers doesn't support this field for whatever reason. Are there any alternatives to the methods I've tried?